# Groovy - Grab: why it continues to download the necessary jars ?

Tags: groovy

I have a script where a method is annotated with the @Grab annotation

```
@Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module='http-builder', version='0.5.2' )
```

everytime i run the script groovy downloads all the required jars from internet, this makes the execution of the script very slow.

Why is it doing this?  It has just downloaded all the necessary jars, i see them in .groovy/grapes

Groovy 1.8.4 on Linux

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's an issue with the [http-builder repo itself](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder/http-builder/0.5.2) having dependencies with a version range.

A possible [workaround is here](http://spring-java-ee.blogspot.com/2011/04/fixing-slow-grab-dependencies-issue.html)

Also, http-builder seems to have a dependency on Groovy [1.5,1.7.99] so no idea what it does when you Grab using Groovy 1.8

Comment: Yep, this is the cause.  I hit this a while ago and was annoyed by it.  I have a comment in my notes about this issue that you can also do a `@GrabExclude("org.codehaus.groovy:groovy")` as well, but I forget if that worked or not.  A really annoying issue that should be tweaked in the httpbuilder dependencies even if what they have is "correct".